# uninitialized local variable 'x' used

Tags: c++

for (int x; x < 32; x++) в чём проблема??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема в том, что в данном выражении: `x < 32` происходит чтение значения неинициализированной переменной `x`.

Comment: нужно присвоить значение этой перменной? например int x = 0;?

Comment: `нужно присвоить значение этой перменной? например int x = 0;?` Да.

Comment: это надо сделать в цикле for (int x=0; x < 32; x++) или перед циклом?

Comment: Если цикл может быть прерван досрочно (`break` по условию) и нужно знать итерацию, на которой был прерван цикл, то инициализируйте перед циклом, чтобы можно было обращаться к переменной `x` после цикла. В противном случае обычно инициализируют в цикле.

Comment: это надо сделать как на этом скриншоте? (ibb.co/RvVJ4nD)

Comment: `for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменную можно объявить. Например `int x;`

Переменную можно инициализировать. Т.е. внести в переменную какое-либо значение.

---

Пока не инициализируешь значение - там мусор.

Собственно в цикле происходит только объявление, но не инициализация

Comment: это надо сделать как на этом скриншоте? (https://ibb.co/RvVJ4nD)

Comment: объявлять и инициализировать можно прямо в первом выражении цикла

Comment: Из занудства :) добавлю, что *Пока не инициализируешь значение - там мусор* не относится к глобальным переменным...

Comment: @Harry, а так же к `static` переменным (не являющихся static members).